# How to enable global application menu in RStudio?

Tags: unity, qt, appmenu, rstudio

On **Ubuntu 15.04 Unity**, how can I enable the global menu bar for the **Qt** application **RStudio**?

I found a 12.04 [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129416/qt-apps-problems-in-ubuntu-12-04), which was not solved and did not contain a clue.

(Due to reputation issues, I could not add the *RStudio* tag).

Comment: Both solutions don't seem to work under Ubuntu 16.04 and the recent RStudio Version 0.99.903 any longer. :(
Is there a new solution for the actual Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit:*

It is reported (see comments), that Ubuntu 16.04 and/or RStudio release 0.99.467 (using Qt5) or later do not support the following solution any more. See also the answer of lyz1990.

---

I found a solution on the RStudio forum ([here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200635228-Integration-with-Ubuntu-global-menu-and-HUD)). The issue has reported several times (e.g. [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200657986-Support-for-Ubuntu-global-menu) and [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200659257-Global-Menu-support-for-Unity-users)).

To enable the `appmenu-qt` for **RStudio**, link the qt4 menubar to the rstudio library folder. Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/menubar
```

Then (close and) start `rstudio`. This is how it looks like:

[image: Enable global application menu with RStudio]

Comment: Your command seems incomplete (the `ln` command usually takes two arguments). Typo?

Comment: Read `man ln` and see the 2nd form. The link name is optional. It is taken from the target name.

Comment: Indeed. I'd still use third or first forms and skip the `cd`: 
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/menubar /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/plugins`.

Comment: Usually I do use it your way, but a line break does not look so nice in the code block...

Comment: No longer seems to work for version 0.99.467, which uses Qt5.

Answer (score 1):

For recent versions of Rstudio with Qt5:

```
cd /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/plugins/platformthemes
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libappmenu-qt5.so libappmenu-qt5.so
```