# How do I enable global menu for RStudio in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, qt, appmenu, r

I tried the solutions mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588844/how-to-enable-global-application-menu-in-rstudio) but neither worked. RStudio version 0.99.896 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: do the menus appear in other software? there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226) where gtk application menus are missing